# Whay am I getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am doing search. But I get error at `each` in search view

`each` for views/housing/index.html.erb is working fine.

But below is `views/search/search_housing.html.erb` wehre I am getting `each`:

```
<tbody>
     <% @housings.each do |housing| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%=link_to "#{housing.title}", housing_path(housing.slug) %></td>
   <td><%= housing.category.name %></td>
```

below is my Housing controller

```
class HousingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_housing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /housings
  # GET /housings.json
  def index
    @housings = Housing.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end

  # GET /housings/1
  # GET /housings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /housings/new
  def new
    @housing = Housing.new
  end

  # GET /housings/1/edit
  def edit
    if not @housing.user_email == current_user.email || current_user.email == "codeinflash@gmail.com"
      redirect_to @housing
    end
  end

  # POST /housings
  # POST /housings.json
  def create
    @housing = Housing.new(housing_params)
    @housing.user_email = current_user.email

    respond_to do |format|
      if @housing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @housing }
        flash[:success] = "Housing was successfully created."
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @housing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /housings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /housings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @housing.update(housing_params)

        format.html { redirect_to @housing }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @housing }
        flash[:success] = "Housing was successfully updated."
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @housing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /housings/1
  # DELETE /housings/1.json
  def destroy
    @housing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to housings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      flash[:alert] = "Housing was successfully destroyed."
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_housing
      @housing = Housing.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def housing_params
      params.require(:housing).permit(:title, :type, :description, :location, :user_email, :created_at, :category_id, :slug)
    end
end
```

Below is my search controller

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
            def search_housing
                    @housings = Housing.search((params[:search].present? ? params[:search] : '*')).records.order(created_at: :desc)
                    # if params[:search].nil?
                    #     @housings = Housing.all.order(created_at: :desc)
                    # else
                    #     @housings = Housing.search params[:search]
                    # end
                end
    end
```

Comment: In your search controller, does it work when you comment out the ' @housings = Housing.all.order(created_at: :desc)' line alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH MAY GOD, I found way..
I just forgot to put an `end` end of the search controller...

Thanks guys!

Comment: You would have gotten a SyntaxError if that were the case, so it was definitely something else. Glad you fixed it though!

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from your view:

```
<% @housings.each do |housing| %>
```

while you are trying to access to @housing which is nil.

Try to put

> raise exception or binding.pry debugger in your controller and check what is the result of your query.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
        def search_housing
                @housings = Housing.search((params[:search].present? ? params[:search] : '*')).records.order(created_at: :desc)
                binding.pry        
        end
end
```

I suppose your query for **Housing.search** returns nil.

To install binding.pry debugger check this link https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails

Cheers.